# Tish'a Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solar year has appx 365 days.

A lunar year has appx 354 days.

The 11 day difference adds up to **209** days on average missing over a 19 year period (11 x 19 = 209) thus 7 out of every 19 years we add in a second Adar to make up for this shortfall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the yishuv in Mitzrayim was 210, and the makkos lasted a year prior  משפט המצריים, שנים עשר חודש ([Mish. Ed. 2:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h47.htm)) , that would be...209!